# Writing json from two lists in Python

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python. I have two lists. One is key list and another list is value list.

```
title = ["Code","Title","Value",....] value = [["100","abcd",100",...],["101","efgh",200",...],...] data={} data.setdefault("data",[]).append({"code": sp[0],"val": sp[2]})
```

this code gives me the following result.

```
{'data': [{'code': '100', 'val': '100'},{'code': '101', 'val': '200'}]}
```

But I want the result as the below,

```
{ "100": { "Title": "abcd", "Value": "100", ............, ............}, "101": { "Title": "efgh", "Value": "200", ............, ............} }
```

i.e., The first column of the value list should be the key of every Json array list and other items of the lists should be generated as key and value pair. How can I generate the Json array using Python code referring that two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is not mentioned that about the size of list ,the below could would do the job.I am using python3.x

```
title = ["Code","Title","Value"]
value = [["100","abcd","100"],["101","efgh","200"]]
dic1={}
for i in range(len(title)-1):
    for j in range(len(title)-1):
        dic1.setdefault(value[i][0],{}).update({title[j+1]:value[i][j+1]})
```

Output is

```
{'101': {'Title': 'efgh', 'Value': '200'}, '100': {'Title': 'abcd', 'Value': '100'}}
```

I hope it is helpful!

Comment: Thank you experiment. It works and much helpful to understand more about Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dict with this lists. I made a quick snippet just for you to understand

```
title = ["Code","Title","Value"]
value = [['100','abcd','100'],['101','efgh','200']]
data={}

for whatever in value:
    your_titles = {}
    print(whatever[0])
    your_titles[title[1]] = whatever[1]
    your_titles[title[2]] = whatever[0]
    your_titles[title[0]] = whatever[2]
    data[whatever[0]] = your_titles
print(data)
```

The output:
{'100': {'Code': '100', 'Value': '100', 'Title': 'abcd'}, '101': {'Code': '200', 'Value': '101', 'Title': 'efgh'}}

Please [read this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) and try to make it yourself. This is not the optimal solution for this problem.

Comment: Thank you Christian. Your solution is easy and more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Make a data frame and then set the column to index and then convert it to json:

```
    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns = title, data = value)
    data = data_frame.set_index('Code')

    json1 = data.to_json(orient='index')
```